# Does anyone know how to create an alphabet tracing app using flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create an app for kids to practice writing letters by tracing points.

Black Line should appear when they follow the clip path

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3TKd.gif)

Comment: https://pschool.in/alphabets/capital-letters I think they built using JavScript.

Comment: This article describes how you can create a simple drawing app using `CustomPaint` and `GestureDetecture` and might be a helpful starting point: https://www.raywenderlich.com/25237210-building-a-drawing-app-in-flutter